# Can I use grep to show only the matched line, and not the file it appeared in?

Tags: grep

I sometimes want to `grep` for a function to see examples of how it is used in context, eg. what sort of parameters it is called with. When I am doing this, the name of the file the match appears in becomes useless clutter. Is there any way to instruct `grep` to not include it? (Or a `grep` alternative that solves the same problem?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell `grep` not to indicate the filename in the output with the option `-h`:

```
   -h, --no-filename
          Suppress the prefixing of file names on  output.   This  is  the
          default  when there is only one file (or only standard input) to
          search.
```

#### Test

```
$ echo "hello" > f1
$ echo "hello man" > f2
$ grep "hello" f*
f1:hello
f2:hello man
$ grep -h "hello" f*
hello
hello man
```